# Proof a formula (circle division into chords) always produces an integer

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

### Some Background

[The formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleDivisionbyChords.html) for the number of pieces a circle can be divided into by joining n points on it's circumference by chords is given by:

$$f(n) = \frac{n^4 - 6n^3 + 23n^2 - 18n}{24} + 1$$

### The Question

I want to show that $f(n)$ always produces a whole number; aka $\forall{n} \in \mathbb{N}, f(n) \in \mathbb{N}$

### My Attempt

Since adding any two numbers in $\mathbb{N}$ results in another number in $\mathbb{N}$, I only need to show that $$\frac{n^4 - 6n^3 + 23n^2 - 18n}{24} \in \mathbb{N}$$

To do this I will show that the polynomial divides $24$.

$$\forall{n} \in \mathbb{N}, n^4 - 6n^3 + 23n^2 - 18n \mid 24$$

As $24$ is not prime I will have to show the polynomial divides the prime constituents of $24$, namely $3$ and $2^3 = 8$.

$$\forall{n} \in \mathbb{N}, n^4 - 6n^3 + 23n^2 - 18n \mid 3$$

First I reduced or removed each term in the polynomial by modding it by $3$.

$$ n^4 - 6n^3 + 23n^2 - 18n \equiv n^4 + 2n^2 \pmod 3$$

By fermat's little theorem: $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$

$$\therefore n^4 + 2n^2  \equiv n \times n^3 + 2n^2 $$
$$ \equiv n \times n + 2n^2 \equiv 3n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$
$$\therefore n^4 - 6n^3 + 23n^2 - 18n \mid 3$$

---

For the second case, that the polynomial divides $8$, I took the same first steps of modding the polynomial by $8$ to reduce the problem.

$$\forall{n} \in \mathbb{N}, n^4 - 6n^3 + 23n^2 - 18n \mid 8$$

$$ n^4 - 6n^3 + 23n^2 - 18n \equiv n^4 + 2n^3 - n^2 - 2n \pmod 8$$

Then I grouped the terms that have the same coefficient, which simplified nicely.

$$ n^4 + 2n^3 - n^2 - 2n \pmod 8$$
$$\equiv n^4 - n^2 + 2n^3 - 2n \pmod 8$$

$$\equiv n^2(n^2 - 1) + 2n(n^2 - 1) \pmod 8$$
$$\equiv (n^2 + 2n)(n^2 - 1) \pmod 8$$

Splitting both parts of the expression into smaller terms yields a nice sequence.

$$\equiv n(n + 2)(n^2 - 1) \pmod 8$$
$$\equiv n(n + 2)(n + 1)(n - 1) \pmod 8$$
$$\equiv (n - 1)n(n + 1)(n + 2) \pmod 8$$

(This is a bit I have trouble showing rigorously and constructively) In any sequence of $4$ consecutive numbers, at least $1$ term must be divisible by $4$, and another must be divisible by $2$. Therefore the product must be divisble by $4 \times 2 = 8$. My proof for this involves a case by case analysis.

$$n \equiv 0, (n - 1)n(n + 1)(n + 2) \equiv (3)0(1)(2) \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$

$$n \equiv 1, (n - 1)n(n + 1)(n + 2) \equiv (0)1(2)(3) \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$

$$n \equiv 2, (n - 1)n(n + 1)(n + 2) \equiv (1)2(3)(0) \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$

$$n \equiv 3, (n - 1)n(n + 1)(n + 2) \equiv (2)3(0)(1) \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$

In all the above cases $1$ term was divisible by $4$ and another had a remainder $2$ when divided by $4$, so it is divisible by 2.

$$\therefore (n - 1)n(n + 1)(n + 2) \equiv 0 \pmod 8$$

---

As the polynomial is divisible by $3$ and $8$, it is divisible by $24$. Thus $\forall{n} \in \mathbb{N}, f(n) \in \mathbb{N}$. $QED$

### Room for Improvement

Is the proof correct? If so, can I simplify this proof?

Comment: Your proof is correct. You should say "$X$ divides (whatever)", not "(whatever) divides $X$" at several places in the proof. I don't think you really need the case by case analysis at the end.

Comment: Ah good point, I messed up the order of a divides b each time. How would I avoid the case by case analysis? I would love to replace it, but I don't know another way of formally writing it.

Comment: As an instructor reading your proof I'd settle for the simple statement that among four consective integers two are divisible by two and one by four. Particularly if you say "exactly" rather than "at least".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is easier to show that $f(n) = {n \choose4} + {n \choose 2} + 1$ since binomial coefficients are always integers. That is, ${n \choose k}\in \mathbb{N}\;  \forall{n,k} \in \mathbb{N}.$ Look at [OEIS sequence A000217](http://oeis.org/A000217) for more information.

Comment: 3blue1brown has a video where he derives this formula in a very understandable way:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8P8uFahAgc

Answer (score 2):

$f(n) = \frac{n^4 - 6n^3 + 23n^2 - 18n}{24} + 1$

Factor the numerator:

$$n(n-1)(n^2-5n+18)$$
$$=n(n-1)[(n-2)(n-3)+12]$$
$$=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)+12n(n-1)$$

It can be proven that any n consecutive integers are divisible by n!.

So the term on the left of the plus sign is divisible by 4!=24. By the same principle, n(n-1) is divisible by 2. Since its initially multiplied by 12, then the whole term on the right of the plus sign is divisible by 24.

The sum of two numbers divisible by 24 is itself divisible by 24.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be shown by induction, with a rather weird method.
You can see after some calculations that: $$(n+1)^4 - 6(n+1)^3 + 23(n+1)^2 - 18(n+1) = (n^4-6n^3+23n^2-18n) + (4n^3-12n^2+32n)$$
Now consider :$$4n^3-12n^2+32n = 4n(n^2-3n+8)$$
Notice that $n^2-3n+8$ is always divisible by $2$. So the expression is always divisible by $8$. Now, if either $n \equiv 0 \pmod 8$ or $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, we always have either $4n \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ or $n^2-3n+8 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$. So $4n(n^2-3n+8)$ is always divisible by $24$.